# Isotope issues - always keep element in top left corner after sorting / filtering

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I am using isotope to filter and sort elements by name or category, descending or ascending within a main container.

I need to keep the first element static so that it is unaffected by sorting / filtering.  I have managed this to get this but working for the first element, however, when a particular filter is added the first element is hidden and so I need the 2nd element (which will be displayed as the first) to become static so I always have a static element visible in the top left hand corner.

The below code works for the first element.  I have tried amending the code below to incorporate the 2nd element to remain static when sorting is applied but am struggling.  Can anyone assist?

```
            var $container = $('#container'),
                 filters = {};
                 $container.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.element',
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: 260
                },
                getSortData: {
                    category: function($elem) {
                        if ($elem.is('.first_static')) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        return $elem.attr('data-category');
                    },
                    date: function($elem) {
                        if ($elem.is('.first_static')) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        return $elem.attr('data-expiry');
                    },
                    name: function($elem) {
                        if ($elem.is('.first_static')) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        return $elem.find('.name').text();
                    },
                    first: function($elem) {
                        // sort by first_static first, then by original order
                        return ($elem.hasClass('first_static') ? -500 : 0) + $elem.index();
                    }
                },
                sortBy: 'first'
            });
```

Im working on a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/AbUgj/24/) to demonstrate what Im trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Add a new class named `show_el` then try following this code.

```
.show_el:first {
    display: static;
}
```

Comment: My query is regards to JQuery Isotope and not CSS as discussed in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a class for all your visible elements, let's call it `visible-element`. Then, you can define this css rule:

```
.visible-element:first {
    display: static;
}
```

You must make sure that all the visible elements have the `visible-element` class and none of the not visible elements have the `visible-element` class though.

Comment: If you look at the css properties in your console, what do you see? Is there another rule dominating the one in your css? Is the rule described in the css applied to the item? Is the file where you typed the css rule linked into your html?

Comment: Isotope inserts the following inline CSS: "position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(5px, 5px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);", which will change depending on the sort or filter.  I therefore don't think that the CSS you suggested will help.  I think it needs to be set in the isotope configuration

Comment: OK, isotope inserts that inline CSS. But can you edit your question and tell me what are the CSS rules? I am particularly interested about the fate of the display attribute. Is isotope inserting anything to override that? Or is isotope deleting and re-generating the items? I think you realize that it is not enough to know what inline css is inserted by isotope. We need to know what is the fate of display and from what source. Open your page in Chrome, open the Chrome console and please read the whole applicable CSS rule set. You might get some useful information from there as described before.

Comment: Hi Lajos, thanks you for your help.  Although, according to the isotope documentation, in order to exclude an element from sorting you use the JQuery code that I have included in my question.  It doesn't mention anything to do with CSS. I have managed to get the first element static but cannot get the second element static after I apply a filter.  I have tried to create a JSFIddle of the issue and have included this in the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how your version does anything different from mine.  What I want is to always keep the 1st element OR the 2nd Element in the top left hand corner.  I don't want them included in the sort.  If the filter is selected, then the 1st element is removed, but I need the 2nd element to stay inthe top left.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: My solution has kept their design. If you want them to exclude from sorting or filtering, then your question is misleading. I suggest that you should ask a separate question with the title "How can I exclude elements from sorting/filtering using isotope?"